# how do i make stepper stop if both sensors are LOW ? im using a adafruit l293d motor shield

Tags: arduino-motor-shield, stepper

I've tried this code below but it doesn't stop it just rapidly switch direction that it looks like it's trembling I think because it always reads the void startF/R thats why it's trembling .

I need help on how to completely stop the stepper if it reads both sensor LOW

```
if (sensLval== LOW || sensRval == LOW){
     steppStop(); 
}
```

this is my void loop code below

```
    void startF()
  {
    motor1.step(10, FORWARD,SINGLE);
    
  }

    void startR()
  {
    motor1.step(10, BACKWARD,SINGLE);
    
  }

    void steppStop(){
  motor1.step(0, BACKWARD, SINGLE);
 
 motor1.step(0, FORWARD, SINGLE);
}

 
    void loop() {
  sensRval=digitalRead(sensR);
  
sensLval=digitalRead(sensL);


  if (sensLval == LOW)

{
    startF();
  }
  
if (sensLval== LOW && sensRval == LOW)

{
     steppStop();
  }

  if (sensRval == LOW)

{
    startR();
  }
  
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isolate your conditions.

You currently check for:

- *Both* sensors LOW at the same time **and**
- *Either* sensor LOW on its own

If *both* are low—don't check for *either* being LOW (which triggers `startX`.)

```cpp
if (sensLval == LOW && sensRval == LOW) {
    steppStop();
} else if (sensLval == LOW) {
    startF();
} else if (sensRval == LOW) {
    startR();
}
```

There may be other considerations as well, but this is enough to get past that issue.

---

Unrelated, but consistent indentation goes a long way towards code readability and helping others be able to reason about code in general. When posting code it's a good idea to format your code as code, [described here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and when you are editing the question.

Comment: Im sorry bout the format , im still learning but i'll be sure to do well next time. The code works now thanks alot! I ddnt know u could code it  that way. That's cool!